# How to zoom page using Firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon, zooming, firefox-addon-sdk

I'd like to zoom in and out webpages using Firefox addon but I can't find anything in documentation [addon docs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/). I'd like to make it work as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>mouse wheel</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>+</kbd>  / <kbd>-</kbd> but it should use my addon. Please help.

Comment: are you developing the add on, or you want to find an add on that already does this for you?

Comment: I'm developing the addon. I've already found few ready to install addons, but I'm going to use my own.

Comment: The I'd suggest un-packing those add-ons and seeing how they do it.

Comment: I think the reason you are not getting responses is that it looks as if you have not done your homework and you have not even taken the time to explain your problem in more details, or post some code that you tried and it did not work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChromeWindow exposes a FullZoom object which allows to programmatically control zoom.

However I don't think you can reach it from the Add-on SDK.

Edit:

In light of Wladimir's answer, I would recommend the following

```
var {activeBrowserWindow} = require("window-utils");
activeBrowserWindow.FullZoom.enlarge();
activeBrowserWindow.FullZoom.reduce();
activeBrowserWindow.FullZoom.reset();
```

While you can't set arbitrary zoom factors, the bonus is that you get housekeeping for free, i.e. per site persistance of the zoom factor.

Check [FullZoom at mxr](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-fullZoom.js)

Answer (score 2):

You need to access a [`browser` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/browser) directly, in a way described in the [full page zoom documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Full_page_zoom). The high-level modules of the Add-on SDK don't provide this kind of access, you have to use the low-level modules to get to the browser windows. For example, to change the zoom level of the currently active tab you would do:

```js
var {activeBrowserWindow} = require("window-utils");
var browser = activeBrowserWindow.gBrowser.selectedBrowser;
browser.markupDocumentViewer.fullZoom = 1.5;  // 150%
```

Unfortunately, the [`window-utils` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.10/packages/api-utils/window-utils.html) is largely undocumented. In addition to the `activeBrowserWindow` property it also provides a `browserWindowIterator` function that is useful if you want to manipulate tabs in all browser windows:

```js
var {browserWindowIterator} = require("window-utils");
for (var window in browserWindowIterator())
  doSomething(window);
```